# Tracing directory contents

Tags: cocoa

How can one trace the content of a directory? The directory here refers to non home and non current directory. Explicitly, I have three directories

1. 10.5.8 - current directory
2. Development
3. Backup

So, how can I undergo file operation like create, accessing or deleting on Development or 
Backup directory other than my current directory?

Regards, 
Lenin

Answer (score 1):

Your terminology is hard to understand. Do you mean you want to monitor a folder (and its children) for changes, read/modify folders/files to which you don't have permission, or both?

To monitor for changes, check out the [FSEvents](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) API.

To obtain permission to perform a privileged operation, check out the [Authorization Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html) API.

Comment: Say when i created a file it automatically creates in working directory, but i want to create in other directory in my system.

Comment: Referring to my question, my current working directory is 10.5.8, but i want to create a new file in development directory. How can i carry out that. Is it fine.

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking. Do you mean general file and folder operations like new, delete, move, copy? NSFileManager will handle the moves/copies/deletes, as well as "new folder". To create new files, it depends on what you want to do. -[NSString writeToFile:atomically:] will create a text file ... you'll need to be a lot more specific. Please try rephrasing (rather than repeating) your question.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. But any way i will make it out.